# Is there a way to access dojo functionality inherited from base modules?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Assume two template based widgets that inherits properties from a single base module, what if the template based widgets need to use functionality from a dojo module like for example "dojo/on"  Is there a way to give each widget the dojo/on functionality without requiring it in each widget? Because once you go beyond a couple widgets, then having to make sure you require that module in each one gets tiresome.  So can we require it only once in the base module from which they inherit?

Comment: if every widget is using the same module, you could probably just add it to the parent widget that they inherit from. over time, if you keep adding more and more "must-have" dependencies, you run the risk of bloating your parent widget into a God-class. but you do gain some reliability knowing that every widget has access to a basic utility like dojo/on

Comment: @worc my issue is if I include it in the parent widget, how to use it from the child? Since normally you pass the module into the function as a parameter, this parameter exists only in the parent.  How to access it form the child?

Answer (score 0):

Giving you some easy button example below.

widget_base.js

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/on",
    "dijit/form/Button"
], function(declare, lang, on, Button){
    return declare(/* path to widget_base */, null, {
        constructor: function() {
        },
        createButton: function() {
            if (!this.button) this.button = new Button();
        },
        hookFunc: function() {
            func = function() {/* activity */}
            if (!this.button) this.createButton();
            on(this.button, /* event */, lang.hitch(this, func));
        }
    });
})
```

widgetA.js

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    /* path to widget_base */
], function(declare, widget_base){
    return declare(/* path to widgetA */, widget_base, {
        constructor: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },
    });
})
```

Thus, in widgetA, you do not need to require dojo/on anymore.

---

Below is my test case.

test.js

```
define([
    "doh/runner",
    /* path to widget_base */
    /* path to widgetA */
], function(doh, widget_base, widgetA) {
    doh.register("test", [{
        runTest: function() {
            wb = new widget_base();
            wb.createButton();
        },{
        runTest: function() {
            wba = new widgetA();
            wba.createButton();
            wba.hookFunc();
        }
    ]);
})
```

Comment: I don't understand, in WidgetA say you want to use on, or lang that was inherited from the base, how would you do that from the constructor of WidgetA?  Directly from widgetA, not just by calling the function defined in the base.